# Error RcppTOML when installing keras on Rstudio linux centos 7

Tags: centos, rstudio

I am trying to install keras on rstudio on my Linux Centos 7 but when it is compliling, I have this error:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppTOML’
* removing ‘/home/rico/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RcppTOML’
```

I tried to install from tar.gz but I still have the error.
Do you have any idea how to resolve it?
Thanks.

Comment: I finally understood, there is a bug on CentOS 7: RcppTOML fails to compile with g++ 4.8.5 (20150623), but installs with g++ 5.3.1 (20160406) from scl-devtoolset-4. `sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install devtoolset-7-gcc*
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash` fixed the issue

Comment: thanks,  but this did not fix the issue for me :/ ...(on R 4.0.0)